# Error when trying to share a website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, sharing

I am trying to create a share link for a specific type of dynamic page on my website. The page has a base template, but then it runs a large PHP script that parses XML to build the actual useful content.

A typical facebook share or like seems to pull the title and content of the base template, not the final page, and this was pretty useless for me, so I found this code to create a custom share link where you can overwrite the title, description, photo, etc:

```
            $title=urlencode($xml->pet->name . ' | DPA!');
            $url=urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
            $summary=urlencode($xml->pet->name . ' is available for adoption.');
            $image=urlencode($thumbnail_photo);

            ?>
            <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Share on Facebook</a></div>
            <?php
```

This pulls up the sharer window as desired with what appears to be the correct info, but when I go to share I get this error:

> The message could not be posted to this Wall

My site is running Wordpress. Can anyone tell me why this error is happening?

Also note that I have tried changing the permissions on the share, tried another browser, and even got my husband to try it on his computer and his account.

Edit: Here is where the code came from: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/

Edit #2: For further information, the page is a "page" in Wordpress with a custom template. The template has a placeholder title which is just "Base Title". The actual displayed title on the page is generated after the fact because I have to read the XML first to find out what the title will be. All of the typical like or share codes I have tried pull "Base Title" as the title of the page I'm sharing. They also don't pull any of the images or text in the content that exists outside the page template. Ergo, they are useless to me.

Edit #3: I put a sample URL into the facebook debugger tool and noticed something odd. Under the redirect section, the original URL was correct but the "rel="canonical"" URL is the URL for the base template. The original URL has an HTML argument that lets the PHP code know what XML to fetch. The "scraped URL" shows what happens when no argument is provided. Don't know if this helps.

Comment: Is there a more complete example or documentation you are following that you could point us to?

Comment: Here is where the code came from: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/

Answer (score 1):

The `sharer.php` endpoint has been deprecated for some time. From what I am seeing on SO, Facebook seems to be disabling it now. You shouldn't depend on this to work. Your example tutorial isn't dated, but the comments go back to July 2011.

The current implementation of the Facebook Share code parses the metadata on the destination page and uses that information.

Based on your description, it sounds like you are calling `get_header()` before you parse your XML file and your "Base Title" is showing up in the page metadata. You can't do that. You'll have to parse your XML first, then call `get_header()`. Your `header.php` will probably also have to be customized to take the correct data from your XML file and use that to generate the metadata.

Comment: I appreciate the insight, but that is a lot of work just for a like button :( I have hundreds of lines of PHP that will not work before get_header()

Comment: You should rethink your project if `get_header()` has to be called before you can process your data. I've got some WP-based sites where I'm processing data outside the WP database with massive amounts of custom code. All of that completes before I generate any output.

Comment: Even after moving the code, I'm still having an issue with facebook using the "canonical URL" rather than the actual URL with argument. The XML and therefore the content of the page depends entirely on an HTML argument but the facebook debugger shows that facebook is only grabbing the part of the URL minus the argument.

Comment: Can you share give some more specific examples (e.g. urls, source code snippets, etc.)?

Comment: I seem to have solved this issue by adding "remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');" to the functions.php